# How to reference underscore and not lodash in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, underscore.js

I have an angular2 app which apparently uses lodash. But I also do have underscore.js with underscore string in the parent project.

Now the typescript compiler complains about missing methods on lodash.
But I am not referring to lodash since the method is in underscore.

```
Property 'classify' does not exist on type 'LoDashStatic'
```

How can I suppress such errors ?

Comment: How are you importing underscore in your TypeScript file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Angular I assume you are using modules

Since you are using modules, you have either a loader or a packager that handles them and you should consume underscore accordingly.

As in Saravana's answer you should start by installing the @types/underscore package.

Additionally make you should uninstall the lodash types if you are not using them

```
npm uninstall --save @types/lodash

npm install --save @types/underscore
```

However, importing directly from an @types package is incorrect usage while using a underscore as a global represents a failure to leverage modules.

Here are examples of how you should reference underscore  after having installed the types package.

**ES Module <=> CommonJS interop style** (preferred)

```
import _ from 'underscore'; // note the absence of @types from the path
```

If TypeScript raises errors for this but it works at runtime, set `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` in your **tsconfig.json** file.

If this fails at runtime, try one of the other approaches.

**TypeScript CommonJS as NameSpace Interop style** (non-standard)

```
import * as _ from 'underscore';
```

**TypeScript CommonJS style** (also works with AMD/UMD)

```
import _ = require('underscore');
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the very detailed explanation. Point being is that I do not want to import underscore within my module. It is already included in another package. By importing it into angular I'd end up with two imported underscore libs, right?! So just getting the code completion and references like this : "import { UnderscoreStatic } from "@types/underscore";" fits my needs.

Comment: _"By importing it into angular I'd end up with two imported underscore libs, right?!"_ no, only if the other package includes it as a global instead of importing correctly.

Comment: But even if you do go with the `declare const _: UnderscoreStatic;` solution, it is a bug waiting to happen that you are importing from `@types`.

Comment: Well the other underscore lib is indeed imported globally and then packaged into one js file with other libs. But this is necessary and wanted because the other libs have do act independently. So how to handle such a situation?

Comment: @dc10 It depends on your build tooling SystemJS, Webpack, and RequireJS have ways of exposing non-global dependencies as globals to work with legacy packages. It may not be worth the trouble though.

Comment: You are right, in this case I would need to expose underscore globally with a webpack export.

Answer (score 1):

You can install `@types/underscore` and then just import that method you want to use and it will not throw any error. Don't forget to add to types in tsconfig.json file